# Moving Exchange 2010 to different machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2010

I'm attempting to move a 110GB Exchange database off of a old machine (see below for specs) to a newer machine ( see below for specs). I've successfully linked the new machine to the old machine's domain, promoted it to a domain controller, and have Active Directory synced perfectly.

What is the proper way to go about this? I followed Microsoft documentation on it to no success.

Specs:

Old: 
Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1
Intel Core 2 Quad Q8400 (yuck)
8GB RAM
1 1TB HDD

New:
Windowss Servers 2008 R2 Standard SP1
Intel Xeon E3-1240 V2
16 GB
2 1TB HDDs

Comment: woah woah woah what? You've promoted the *new server* to a *domain controller* before installing *exchange* on it?

Comment: Should of included that. I installed Exchange BEFORE promoting it. I can access all the mailboxes from the new machine and users can send/receive mail from the new machine as long as the old one is kept on, which is correct I'm assuming since they are on the same domain.

Comment: Professional version: Get real and do not run exchange on a domain controller. Seriously.

Comment: That's the end goal is to get the exchange server off the Domain Controller.

Comment: The question is, why did you add the DC role to an Exchange server? Is this question really "how do I uninstall a DC"

Comment: I know how to remove a DC from a domain, I just need to move the database over to the new hardware.

Comment: But why would you make the Exchange server a DC at all?

Comment: I'm not sure my thought process on that.

Comment: There is pretty much never a good reason to do something like that.  DCs should only be DCs, and have only directory things on them.  You might want to start over, assuming that won't result in data loss - your question is terribly vague.

Comment: I've already started over and back to where I was, minus the domain controller. I think my question is pretty simple. How can I get Exchange 2010 mailbox database from old to new server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new Database and then Move the mailboxes over. 
In EMC, right click mailboxes and choose "New Local Move Request", then work the wizard.

Or use EMS and use e.g.:

```
Get-Recipient | where {$_.ServerName -eq "<servername>"} | New-MoveRequest -TargetDatabase <targetdbname>
```

after moving all mailboxes, you can start decommissioning the old server.